# Using socket to get Minecraft bots join through a proxy (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, minecraft, socks

I need help with my minecraft bot client. I have gotten it working, but I have a problem with socket, it keeps throwing me error codes all the time. Here is the "critical" part of the code:

```
def connect(ip, port, username, indelay, joindelay):
    global running

    if not running:
        return;
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s = s.socksocket()
    s.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,"183.60.143.121, 1080")

    s.connect((ip, port))
    login = (chr(len(username)+2) + chr(0) + chr(len(username)) + username).encode("utf-8")
    s.sendall(handshake)
    s.sendall(login) 
    print("Pelaaja "+username+" liittyi")
    time.sleep(indelay/2)
    s.sendall(('\x02\x16' + chr(2)).encode('utf-8'))
    try:
        for x in spam:
            if(len(x)==0): continue
            s.sendall(chat(x))
    except socket.error:
        pass
    time.sleep(indelay/2)
    s.close()
    print("Pelaaja "+username+" lopetti")
    time.sleep(joindelay)
    connect(ip, port, getRandomUsername(), indelay, joindelay)'
```

Comment: `it keeps throwing me error codes all the time` What error codes? Have you looked up what they mean?

Comment: @MrLore " we read the spam.txt! The length of it was: 47
Starting!
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Laamis\Desktop\Cccpwat\Cccpwat 2.0\Cccpwat 2.0.py", line 32, in connect
    s = s.socksocket()
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'socksocket' "